# C# query inside a for loop returns only one value

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, for-loop

I am building a C# WinForms app in which users able to check with a randomly generated chassis number list if a chassis number for a specific action is connected to a part list and if yes the available part numbers are counted. Each chassis number connects to one part list (or not). That specific part list contains parts that are linked to chassis numbers via type defining notes. For example 100024 has a type defining note of D13K420, therefore it should see in part list 13080554 lines with that type defining notes (count 3).

I have two data tables in MSSQL Server. One for chassis numbers:

```
| ID | chassis_number | model | build_date | factory | type_defining_note | partlist |
|----|----------------|-------|------------|---------|--------------------|----------|
|  1 |         100000 |     1 | 2014-01-04 |       2 |            D13K500 | 13080553 |
|  2 |         100001 |     1 | 2014-01-06 |       2 |            D13K460 | 13080554 |
|  3 |         100002 |     1 | 2014-01-12 |       2 |            D13K460 | 13080554 |
|  4 |         100023 |     1 | 2014-01-15 |       2 |            D13K540 | 13080553 |
|  5 |         100024 |     1 | 2014-01-20 |       1 |            D13K420 | 13080554 |
|  6 |         100025 |     1 | 2014-01-26 |       2 |            D13K500 | 13080553 |
|  7 |         122312 |     1 | 2014-02-08 |       1 |            D13K500 |        0 |
|  8 |         104560 |     1 | 2014-02-09 |       1 |            D13K460 |        0 |
|  9 |         100045 |     1 | 2014-03-04 |       2 |            D13K540 |        0 |
| 10 |         100046 |     1 | 2014-03-12 |       2 |            D13K540 |        0 |
```

And for part lists:

```
| ID | part_list_no | part_list_description | model | position | part_number | part_description | quantity | type_defining_note | action | action_type |
|----|--------------|-----------------------|-------|----------|-------------|------------------|----------|--------------------|--------|-------------|
|  1 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        1 |    21803087 |           Filter |        1 |            D13K500 |      1 |           P |
|  2 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        1 |    21803088 |           Filter |        1 |            D13K540 |      1 |           P |
|  3 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        2 |    24523486 |       Oil cooler |        1 |            D13K500 |      1 |           S |
|  4 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        2 |    24523486 |       Oil cooler |        1 |            D13K540 |      1 |           S |
|  5 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        3 |    27647538 |           O-ring |        2 |            D13K500 |      1 |           S |
|  6 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        3 |    27647538 |           O-ring |        2 |            D13K540 |      1 |           S |
|  7 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        4 |    23984567 |             Pipe |        1 |                    |      0 |             |
|  8 |     13080553 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        5 |    23984558 |             Pipe |        1 |                    |      0 |             |
|  9 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        1 |    21803085 |           Filter |        1 |            D13K420 |      1 |           P |
| 10 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        1 |    21803086 |           Filter |        1 |            D13K460 |      1 |           P |
| 11 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        2 |    24523486 |       Oil cooler |        1 |            D13K420 |      1 |           S |
| 12 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        2 |    24523482 |       Oil cooler |        1 |            D13K460 |      1 |           S |
| 13 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        3 |    27647538 |           O-ring |        2 |            D13K420 |      1 |           S |
| 14 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        3 |    27647538 |           O-ring |        2 |            D13K460 |      1 |           S |
| 15 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        4 |    23984567 |             Pipe |        1 |                    |      0 |             |
| 16 |     13080554 |   Oil filter (Engine) |     1 |        5 |    23984558 |             Pipe |        1 |                    |      0 |             |
```

The connection made with a simple join: `FULL OUTER JOIN part_list ON chassis.part_list = part_list.part_list_number`

What I would like achieve is this:

```
| chassis_number | parts |
|----------------|-------|
|         100000 |     3 |
|         100001 |     3 |
|         100002 |     3 |
|         100023 |     3 |
|         100024 |     3 |
|         100025 |     3 |
|         100045 |     0 |
|         100046 |     0 |
|         104560 |     0 |
|         122312 |     0 |
```

If there is a connection between the chassis number and part list, count all the part numbers that has a valid connection via type defining note, if not simply return a 0.

I was able to create a query which counts the parts, but putting it inside a for loop in C# returns parts only for one chassis number or if multiple chassis number was given returns 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(chassis.chassis_number) AS parts FROM chassis FULL OUTER JOIN part_list ON chassis.part_list = part_list.part_list_number WHERE chassis.chassis_number = @chassisnumber AND part_list.action = @action AND part_list.type_defining_note LIKE(SELECT chassis.type_defining_note FROM chassis WHERE chassis.chassis_number = @chassisnumber)
```

And the code that should return the counted parts:

```
public static void CheckPackages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chassisNumber.Count; i++)
    {
        Variables.searchChassisNumber = Convert.ToInt32(chassisNumber[i]);

        try
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(chassis.chassis_number) AS parts FROM chassis FULL OUTER JOIN part_list ON chassis.part_list = part_list.part_list_number WHERE chassis.chassis_number = @chassisnumber AND part_list.action = @action AND part_list.type_defining_note LIKE(SELECT chassis.type_defining_note FROM chassis WHERE chassis.chassis_number = @chassisnumber)";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlParameter paramChassisNumber = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@chassisnumber",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = Variables.searchChassisNumber
            };

            SqlParameter paramAction = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@action",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = Variables.selectedAction
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < part.Count; j++)
            {
                part.RemoveAt(j);
            }

            command.Parameters.Add(paramChassisNumber);
            command.Parameters.Add(paramAction);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                part.Add((int)reader["parts"]);
            }
            reader.Close();
            command.Parameters.Clear();

            partList.Add(new Parts(chassisNumber[i], part[i]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I read on other answers here that running a query inside a loop is not too wise (performance issues, in my case there might be some other failure in my code).

Link to sample database on SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d4638/74

The question is: what options are available for me to get a working solution? Should I put inside a for loop my query, or create a new parameterised query, or should I rebuilt the whole database to make it work?

Comment: It seems that you could replace the loop with `part.RemoveAt(j);` with a single call to `part.Clear();` (no loop needed). But is that your intent? To empty the `part` list at that point in the code?

Comment: I saw somewhere this method for emptying a list. It is ok for now but when the whole thing works, I will clean up and optimise my code. My problem is that when the loop runs only the first element of the given list (chassisNumber) has been executed. I need the other elements of the chassisNumber list to be included as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. avoid loop it at the front-end, it is bad for performance.

You are almost on the right track.

you need chassis LEFT OUTER JOIN to partlist on 3 conditions partlist, type_defining_note and action

then GROUP By the chassis_number and couting partlist (and not count(*) as you only want to count those there exists in partlist table)

```
select chassis.chassis_number, count(partlist.part_list_no) as parts
from   chassis
       left join partlist on  chassis.partlist = partlist.part_list_no
                          and chassis.type_defining_note = partlist.type_defining_note
                          and partlist.action = '1' 
group by chassis.chassis_number
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works well on the whole chassis table, but I need to run this query only on selected chassis numbers (chassisNumber in the for loop), to see if those have a "package" (=has a connection to a part list, if yes count all the part numbers  which fit the condition: each chassis number has a type defining note, part numbers as well, this connection should be considered).

Comment: why you want to do it one at a time when you can do it all in one go

Comment: I will use your query to get all the "packages", then narrow my search with the "chassisNumber" list. Thanks!